# Pig Latin - strings

Tags: c++, string

So I am supposed to convert English words to Pig Latin using stringConvertToPigLatin(string word) function. All the answers I could find on the internet were using char[], and I am not allowed to do so.
The program is supposed to begin with adding -way if the first letter is a vowel, and adding -ay if it's a consonant. The problem is that it is always adding "-way", even if my "word" has no vowel at all. What am I doing wrong? This is my function:

```
string ConvertToPigLatin(string word)
{
char first = word.at(0);
cout << first << endl;
if (first == 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'E' || 'i' || 'I' || 'o' || 'O' || 'u' || 'U')
{
    word.append("-way");
}
else
{
    word.append("-ay");
}
return word;
}
```

Comment: It should be `if (first == 'a' || first == 'A' || first == 'e' || ...)`     ...

Comment: A tip: Use full warnings, and heed them. Your compiler should have warned you about the constant conditional. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments your `if` statement is wrong. Each comparison needs to be done individually. From the comment.

```
if (first == 'a' || first == 'A' || first == 'e' || ...)
```

However, rather than using a long `if` statement you should consider stuffing all of the vowels into a `string` and using `find`. Something like the code below will be easier to read and follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string ConvertToPigLatin(std::string word)
{
    static const std::string vowels("aAeEiIoOuU");
    char first = word.at(0);
    std::cout << first << std::endl;
    if (vowels.find(first) != std::string::npos)
    {
        word.append("-way");
    }
    else
    {
        word.append("-ay");
    }
    return word;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << ConvertToPigLatin("pig") << '\n';
    std::cout << ConvertToPigLatin("alone") << '\n';
}
```

This outputs

> p
>   pig-ay
>   a
>   alone-way

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain why your code isn't working:

```
if (first == 'a' || 'A' || 'e' || 'E' || 'i' || 'I' || 'o' || 'O' || 'u' || 'U')
```

Let's walk through that iff statement using the word "Pig"

First the program checks first == 'a'... first == 'P' so that is false.
Then the program checks to see if false || 'A' is true. Since 'A' is true, false || 'A' is also true.
Short circuit evaluation kicks in, and the code doesn't bother checking the rest of the statement, the if condition is true so -way is appended.

To do what you want, you need to compare first to each letter. I.E.,

```
if (first == 'a' || first == 'A' || ...
```

Don't worry too much, this is a pretty standard mistake.